# How do make div to scroll on key up and down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the link of [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/9486/). I'm trying to scroll within dialog box using up and down key. I can scroll by using mouse, but came to know how do scroll up and down using keys. Here is what I am trying so far.

```
var element = document.getElementById("scroll-to-here");
        element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
```

Actually I'm trying to scroll 15px; or 20px up or down on key up and down.

Answer (score 2):

use `scrollTop` function:

```
$("#yourElement").scrollTop(10);
```

in your case, increase or decrease the scroll top depending on the button being pressed.

```
var $el = $("#yourElement");
$el.scrollTop($el.scrollTop() - 10); //move the scrollbar upwards
```

see this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/po6bokz6/

Comment: scrollTop is undefined . Also I don't want to scroll to element. I want to move scroll certain px on each up and down , up in case of up key down in case of down key.

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed? Also, attach the event handler when the page is loaded. See live example in my answer.

Comment: is installed but I am using bootstrap model window for popup. scroll is not working in popup.

Comment: Did you see my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
   modal: true,
   draggable: false,
   resizable: false,
   position: ['center', 'top'],
   show: 'blind',
   hide: 'blind',
   width: 400,
   dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
   buttons: {
      "I've read and understand this": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
      }
   }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 switch(e.which) {

    case 38: // up
    var y = $('#to-scroll').scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
    $('#to-scroll').scrollTop(y-150);


    break;

    case 39: // right
    break;

    case 40: // down
     var y = $('#to-scroll').scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
       $('#to-scroll').scrollTop(y+150);


    break;

    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
}
//e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

see this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/9488/

Comment: Height of popup will be increased based on ajax content , also element in such case will be unknown.